# How can I program the RiemannR function using the LogIntegral command?

Tags: special-functions, number-theory

I would like to program the `RiemannR` function using the `LogIntegral` command
because I would like to later experiment with a double integral instead of the
`LogIntegral` function.

I have tried to program the `RiemannR` function starting with the
`LogIntegral` command as defined in the [Stein-Mazur paper called "Primes"](http://modular.math.washington.edu/rh/):

[image: RiemannR function as in Stein Mazur paper on primes]

That agrees almost completely with the definition given in the *Mathematica*
help page about the `RiemannR` command:

$$R(x)=\sum_n^\infty \mu(n)\mathrm{li}(x^{1/n})/n$$

The only differences I see are that the summation limit $n=1$ is given
in the Stein-Mazur paper while in the *Mathematica* help page it is not.
Also the Stein-Mazur paper uses $\mathrm{Li}$ for the logarithmic integral while
the *Mathematica* help page uses $\mathrm{li}$. However in the *Mathematica* help
page for the `LogIntegral` command the lower case $\mathrm{li}$ is used.

My problem is that when I enter the following lines:

```
N[RiemannR[1000]]
N[Sum[MoebiusMu[n]*LogIntegral[1000^(1/n)]/n, {n, 1, Infinity}]]
```

in *Mathematica*, I get different numerical values:

```
168.359
168.341
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are investigating the prime number theorem, please note the chapter on the zeta function in Wagon's Mathematica In Action, where he refers to a book by H.M. Edwards called Riemann's Zeta Function.
Wagon cautions that `ExpIntegralEi[r Log[x]]` must be used instead of `LogIntegral[x^r]` when x is real and r is complex. This is because the complex log function returns `r Log[x]-2 Pi n i`, with n chosen to make the imaginary part lie between -Pi and Pi, which leads to incorrect sums.

Comment: @Kenny, yes, that's another good reason to use `ExpIntegralEi[]`, at least in this context. (I had forgotten to point out that Stan Wagon indeed discussed Riemann's function in his book.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found that `NSum[]` takes a bit too long here to compute Riemann's prime-counting function, so I've resorted to generating the terms and summing them:

```
With[{n = 8*^3},
     Total[MoebiusMu[Range[n]] N[LogIntegral[1000^(1/Range[n])]/Range[n]],
           Method -> "CompensatedSummation"]]
   168.35915686601484
```

which gives a result close to that of `RiemannR[]`:

```
% - RiemannR[1000]
   -0.000289415
```

It is, however, faster (at least in some of the tests I did) to exploit an identity connecting the logarithmic integral and the exponential integral $\mathrm{Ei}(z)$:

```
With[{n = 8*^3}, 
     Total[MoebiusMu[Range[n]] N[ExpIntegralEi[Log[1000]/Range[n]]/Range[n]],
           Method -> "CompensatedSummation"]]
```

But, the best method to compute Riemann's function would be to use [Gram's series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GramSeries.html):

$$R(x)=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(\log\,x)^k}{k k!\zeta(k+1)}$$

In *Mathematica*:

```
1 + NSum[(Log[1000]^k)/(k k! Zeta[k + 1]), {k, 1, ∞}]
```

As it turns out, if you inspect how *Mathematica* internally implements `RiemannR[]`, you'll find that Gram's series is indeed used for large arguments. (In particular, look at `` NumberTheory`NumberTheoryFunctionsDump`PlainRiSeries[] ``.)